# Why I'm I getting this error in my terminal while uploading to s3? What I'm I not writing right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm getting this error in the terminal

"Missing required key 'Bucket' in params"

This is how my code looks like

```
 const s3 = new S3({
  region,
  accessId,
  secretAccessKey, 
})


// Uploads to s3 
function uploadFile(file){
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path)

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: BucketName,
    Body: fileStream,
    Key: file.filename 
  }

  return s3.upload(uploadParams, (err, file) => {
    if(err){
      console.log("problem uploading to s3", err)
    }
    console.log("Upload successful", file)
  }).promise();
}
```

And I tried getting the result here:

```
app.post("/news_feed", upload.single("image"),  async (req, res) => {
            const file = req.file
            console.log(file)
             
            const result = await uploadFile(file)
            console.log(result)
            
});
```

What I'm I not writing right?

Comment: Are you sure that `BucketName` is defined and has value when the code reach that line?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in a config file